# Is there an actual way to launch developer settings directly?

Tags: android

I checked the [official settings page on the developer website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html), I checked google, there seems to be no way to programmatically launch android the developer settings. How do apps [like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fungaljungal.devsettingswidget) do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this code:**

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS), 0);
```

For more settings ACTIONS you can pass through [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) or in [particular here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS).